# Close Bootstrap navbar by default

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm new to bootstrap and am trying to configure a left side nav-bar to be closed by default on page load so the user must click the menu link to open the menu.  The page is a content-heavy dashboard that needs as much real estate as I can get it.

Here's the relevant code:

```
<nav class="navbar-default navbar-static-side" role="navigation">
    <div class="sidebar-collapse">
        <ul class="nav metismenu" id="side-menu">
            <li class="nav-header">
                <div class="dropdown profile-element">
                        <a href="index.html"><img src="img/lc-logo.png" width="172"/></a>
                        <a data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" href="#">
                            <span class="clear"> <span class="block m-t-xs"> <strong class="font-bold">(username)</strong></span> 
                            <span class="text-muted text-xs block">(user role) <b class="caret"></b></span> </span>
                        </a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu animated fadeInRight m-t-xs">
                            <li><a href="#">Logout</a></li>
                        </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="logo-element">
                    LC
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="active">
                <a href="index.html"><i class="fa fa-calendar-o fa-lg"></i> <span class="nav-label">Schedule</span></a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="index.html"><i class="fa fa-th fa-lg"></i> <span class="nav-label">Releases</span></a>
                <ul class="nav nav-second-level">
                    <li class="active"><a href="release.html">v2.3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="release.html">v2.6</a></li>
                    <li><a href="release.html">v2.7</a></li>
                    <li><a href="release.html">v3.0 <span class="label label-primary pull-right">NEW</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="offcycle.html">Off Cycle <span class="label label-primary pull-right">NEW</span></a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="testing.html"><i class="fa fa-bug fa-lg"></i> <span class="nav-label">Test Status</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="stats.html"><i class="fa fa-bar-chart fa-lg"></i> <span class="nav-label">Stats</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="settings.html"><i class="fa fa-cogs fa-lg"></i> <span class="nav-label">Settings</span></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this easily by having your `nav` set to hidden in your CSS and then have it tied to a `button` to call it on a click event.

Give your nav an id of nav it should look like this now:

```
 <nav id="nav" class="navbar-default navbar-static-side" role="navigation">
```

Next create a button outside of your nav tag like so:

```
<a href="#" id="btn" class="btn btn-default">Toggle</a>
```

Set your CSS for `#nav` to:

```
#nav{
   display:none;
}
```

This will hide your navigation by default.

In your JS file create this:

```
$('#btn').on('click',function(){
   $('#nav').slideToggle();
});
```

Now your navigation will be hidden by default and will display when you click the button.

[CODEPEN DEMO](http://codepen.io/Gothburz/pen/rOKZdN)